# Why is Excel rejecting CHOOSECOLS(Array,Colnum) in a formula where it accepts INDEX(Array,0,ColNum)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

### SUMMARY

Can anyone explain why Excel -- current versions on both Mac and Windows -- sometimes refuses to accept, in a cell's formula, this:

`CHOOSECOLS(SomeArray,ColNum)`

but it does accept this:

`INDEX(SomeArray,0,ColNum)`

Two specific examples are when those forms are used within a SUMIF() or a COUNTIF() function. And when I say Excel refuses to accept the former, I mean I can't even get it to accept it as a syntactically correct formula. I note that non-conditional versions of those functions do ***not*** show the problem, nor do functions such as MAX(), MIN(), AVERAGE(), etc.

### DETAILS

Suppose I have an array in B5:C10 (assume it's dynamic, so I can refer to it neatly as B5# in the following examples; but the problem exists even with non-dynamic ranges as well), and I want to sum all items greater than 0 in column 2 (i.e. in C5:C10). While Excel accepts the following:

`=SUMIF(INDEX(B5#,0,2),">0")`

it refuses to accept:

`=SUMIF(CHOOSECOLS(B5#,2),">0")`

However, if I first extract the desired column into a helper array rooted in C16 (say) as follows:

`=CHOOSECOLS(B5#,2)`

then the following is accepted as a correct formula (and it gives the correct result):

`=SUMIF(C16#,">0")`

I have an Excel sheet that shows this in action, but I'm not sure of the best way to attach it. If it would be useful, and someone can explain how I can attach a .xlsx file, I'll provide it. Meantime, here's a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUMIF` and other functions you listed are so-called RACON functions, that require a range input. (you can read more about it [here](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) )

That it works with INDEX is a small surprise to me to be honest, but I guess Excel still interpret that as a range input.
If you would've used `=SUMIF(INDEX(B5#,{1;2},2),">0")` it wouldn't be accepted as a range anymore, but it's recognized as an array, which is not an accepted input.

We can bypass this problem by looking into other Excel functions that are not limited to range input, such as MMULT. While it's slightly less straightforward than SUMIFS, let me try to explain the logic:

`MMULT` uses **m**atrix **mult**iplication.
if you have 2 matrixes:

[image]

MMULT will multiply the first row of matrix1 against the transposed first column values of matrix 2:
`={1,2,3}*{10;20;30}`
the sum of these products is the first MMULT result: `10+40+90= 140`

next it will multiply the first row values of matrix1 to the next transposed column of matrix2:
`={1,2,3}*{4;5;6}` = `4+10+18= 32`

next the second row of matrix1 against the first transposed column of matrix2:
`={4,5,6}*{10;20;30}` = `40+100+180= 320`

and finally the second row of matrix1 against the second transposed column of matrix2:
`={4,5,6}*{4;5;6}` = `16+25+36= 77`

This results in:
[image]

so more visual:
[image]

*Why am I telling this?*

`SUMIFS` can't take arrays as the range argument, but MMULT can and we can use similar logic as SUMIFS inside MMULT we just need to multiply it by an array of the same height (# of rows) as the width (# of columns) of the input array.

So to get back at `B5#` and translated the SUMIFS arguments to MMULT would be:
`=MMULT(TOROW(CHOOSECOLS(B5#,2)),N(CHOOSECOLS(B5#,2)>0))`
or
`=LET(b,CHOOSECOLS(B5#,2),MMULT(TOROW(b),N(b>0)))`

It transposes the values of `CHOOSECOLS(B5#,2)` to a row and multiplies them to a vertical array of Booleans *(`CHOOSECOLS(B5#,2)` values to be greater than 0 TRUE or FALSE), where the TRUE and FALSE are converted to their numeric representation `1` and `0` respectively.*
This is then SUMMED.

but in this case we could also make use of the boolean inside SUM:
`=LET(b,CHOOSECOLS(B5#,2),SUM(b*(b>0)))`

*Then why bother the MMULT explanation?*

Because MMULT also has the ability to spill a result array:

So in your case, if we were to sum the values greater than 0 row wise, we'd either have to manually drag the SUM version, or use a BYROW LAMBDA version, but MMULT can perfectly do it as well in one go, without manually dragging:

`=MMULT((B5#>0)*B5#,{1;1})` would spill:
[image]

or a COUNTIF equivalent:
`=MMULT(N(B5#>0),{1;1})`
[image]

Comment: Maybe this is of use as well:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPCgYFydsB5XSBrZ7r6tg?e=XTFfE1

Answer (score 0):

Just nest a couple of Take() functions.  I think the easiest work around to Choosecols in these functions (Sumif, Sumifs, Countif & Countifs) is to nest the Take function to replace Choosecols.

If you need the 3rd column in a 4 column dynamic range, Take(Take(range#,,3),,-1) will return only the third column as a range.

```
Take(Take(range#,,3),,-1)
```