# How to group a column based on another column. Then write it into another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

How to group the **animal name** column based on the **category** column, and put it on the corresponding column (yellow area). For example in the figure, find the animal name (column A) with herbivore (column B) category, and put it in column C (yellow area).

If each item in herbivore has a 30 score, write the total item times 30 to the total (cell labelled X1)

[image: example of the desired result]

Answer (score 1):

Please read the description of the [**FILTER() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) and apply it to your data:

`=FILTER($A$2:$A$29,$B2:$B29=C$2)`

Now read the description of the [**COUNTIF() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) and put in the thirtieth row

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$29,C$2)*30`

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged Microsoft Excel 2016 you need the bypass FILTER not being available. We could achieve this using INDEX and AGGREGATE:

Use this in `C3` use the formula below and drag down/right:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$3:$B$29)/($B$3:$B$29=C$2),ROW(A1))),"")`

We use AGGREGATE with the row numbers of column B from where the range of category starts till where it ends: `B3:B29`. We use `$` to lock the position of the range rows and columns.

The array of row numbers is divided by the Boolean of the cell's value in the array being equal to the value of `C2` resulting in TRUE or FALSE row wise.

Because we use a `/` operator to the array, the Boolean is transformed to it's numerical equivalent: `TRUE` = `1`, `FALSE` = `0`.

So the array of row numbers is divided by an array of `1`'s and `0`'s.
We take advantage of the (row) number divided by `0` resulting in an error (#DIV/0!); AGGREGATE's second argument: `6` means *ignore error values*.
So that means AGGREGATE will only use the array of row numbers meeting the condition, but the first argument has to make it return the `n`th position of that array. We can use `14` SMALL, or `15` LARGE to return the `n`th position of the aggregated array. I used `ROW(A1)` (equals 1) for the first - which will become `A2` (equals 2), etc. - when dragged down.

IFERROR is used if the `n`th row number exceeds the number of rows of the aggregated array, which would return an error for the index.

For the INDEX I used whole column reference, so we don't need to calculate the row minus the start of the array +1 making it unnecessarily complicated.

For the Total you could use SUMPRODUCT in `C30` (drag to the right):
`=SUMPRODUCT(N($B$3:$B$29=C$2))*30`

The same Boolean logic is used as in the aggregate function and `N()` is used to transform the TRUE and FALSE to 1 and 0. SUMPRODUCT sums th 1's and 0`s and the result is multiplied by 30.

If you have a more recent Excel (2021, Office 365) you could spill the totals in one go using:
`=MMULT(TOROW(N(B3:B29<>"")*30),N(B3:B29=C2:E2))`.

*more info on MMULT [here](https://superuser.com/a/1814816/1856315)*

Comment: You could do the SUMPRODUCT in one go, if that's the end goal.

Comment: Yes `FILTER()` wont work with `Excel-2016`. `INDEX()`+`AGGREGATE()` is more robust for other versions!