# Filter Across Multiple Row Labels in Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I want to do the following transformation in excel based on a bunch of sent/received messages:

| Sender A | Sender B | Sender C | Receiver A | Receiver B | Receiver C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

|  | Receiver A | Receiver B | Receiver C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sender A | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Sender B | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| Sender C | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I thought Pivot Tables would help, but the two limitations I'm hitting so far are:

1. Can't use the columns headers from the original table as row labels in the Pivot Table, only their values appear
2. Can't use filters across row labels so that only one row appears per column

Answer (score 2):

This is perfect for MMULT using Office 365:

`=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A2:C5),D2:F5)`

In older Excel you need to wrap it in INDEX and drag to the right/down:
`=INDEX(MMULT(TRANSPOSE($A$2:$C$5),$D$2:$F$5),ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1))`

I believe this requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` but I'm unable to test this.

Or using Office 365, inclusing headers:

```
=LET(sender,A1:C5,
     receiver,D1:F5,
VSTACK(HSTACK("",
              TAKE(receiver,1)),
       HSTACK(TOCOL(TAKE(sender,1)),
              MMULT(TRANSPOSE(DROP(sender,1)),DROP(receiver,1)))))
```

[image]

*See more explained about MMULT [here](https://superuser.com/a/1814816/1856315)*

Comment: Thanks for the information! I think that looks promising. To add another wrinkle: I oversimplified my example a bit; in practice there are thousands of columns and thousands of rows to transform in this manner. I’m assuming an MMULT solution would still work?

Comment: I think it should be alright. Try and you'll see.